# Como fazer uma página ser acessível apenas a usuários com certo nível

Tags: php, mysqli

Bom dia, tenho um sistema de login com php e mysql, no banco de dados tenho 2 usuários, um tem nível Admin (0) e o outro Mestre (1), tenho a página de login que pede Nome de Usuário e Senha da pessoa e verifica se os dados inseridos batem com o BD, após fazer o login corretamente, a página redireciona o usuário para uma página dos admins do sistema, nessa página há um menu lateral aonde tem vários botões, cada um redirecionando para uma página, como a página Postar e a Alterações.
Aqui está o meu problema: a página usuários, esta página só deve ser acessada pelos usuários cujo nível seja Mestre (ou 1), porém não sei como faria isso, tentei utilizar de sessions e query, mas sempre acaba dando em erro ou deixando passar qualquer usuário ao invés de barrar os que são Admin (ou 0).

Comment: Qualquer duvida que tiver referente a resposta de baixo da um toque

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara eu acredito muito na reutilização de código e projetos, por essa razão acredito que você poderia ir no site https://aspnetboilerplate.com/ e criar um projeto com um template pronto ao invés de ir do 0, nesse template você encontra todas suas necessidades e pode configurar novas de acordo com o que for necessário, nele você tem Tenents (que seriam ambientes) e dentro dos ambientes você pode configurar usuários com levels (já tem uma boa base de levels ai você adapta a suas necessidades)

Página para visualização do projeto "rodando" https://gurayyarar.github.io/AdminBSBMaterialDesign

Página do GitHub: https://github.com/gurayyarar/AdminBSBMaterialDesign

Pagina para criação do template: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates